# Brightness Overlay Changing instantly from min to max alpha instead of Incrementing

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a brightness overlay that can be changed by the user using a slider. I'm using a panel (Color is black) for the overlay and editing its alpha with the slider. The slider has a min value of 0 and max of 150, but the slider only has to be 1 or greater for the alpha of the overlay to be at full. When I print the alpha to the console, it says it's only 1, but the alpha on the overlay says is at max (Check gif if there's confusion). How do I set the alpha of an overlay through script using a slider?

- [Scripts](https://github.com/Ethan-Shap/2D-Racer)
- [Gif Of What is happening](https://gyazo.com/fcc2340894753b39406b464436f1156a)

Reasearch:

- [Brightness slider?](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/brightness-slider.39338/)
- [Changing Alpha Material](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/changing-the-alpha-component-of-a-material.893/)
- [Changing Current Alpha](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/178610/how-do-i-get-the-current-alpha-value-of-a-material.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked at your code and found the problem.

Things to understand:

Color.a/Alpha min is 0.0f;

Color.a/Alpha max is 1.0f

Color.a/Alpha = `float` **not** `int`.

So change your `public void ChangeBrightness(int brightness)` to `public void ChangeBrightness(float brightness)`.

On your Slider, make sure that `Min Value` =0 and `Max Value` =1; Also make sure that `Whole Numbers` is not selected.

Right now, the value from the slider is being converted into 0 or 1 due to the `int` in your function parameter. That's why that weird problem is happening.

[image]